# Nested Loop for Dict of Lists

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic way of iterating through a dict of lists while still being able to reference the key and the individual value within the list?

```
my_dict = {
  'fruits': [
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'banana'
  ],
  'animals': [
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'monkey'
  ],
  'colors': [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'yellow'
  ]
}

for k in my_dict.keys():
  for v in my_dict[k]:
    # do some stuff with v
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Comment: `for (k, v) in my_dict.items():`

Comment: Deleted my comment as I misunderstood the attempt. Your way of getting this output is reasonable. You could do something gross like `print('\n'.join([f'{k}: {vitem}' for k,v in my_dict.items() for vitem in v ]))` instead, but nobody in your operations team is going to like you and it's pretty much the same logic packed into an ugly list comprehension.

Comment: TBH nested for loops seems appropriate since you do have nested data.  You can use `for k, (v0, v1, v2) in my_dict.items():` to remove one level of nesting, but only if you expect the same length list for each value.

Answer (score -2):

Use `my_dict.items()` to get the keys and values at the same time.

```
for k, l in my_dict.items():
    for v in l:
        print(f'{k}: {v}')
```